# Samba ignoring netbios name

Tags: samba, netbios

I am trying to configure a new samba (3.6.9-151.el6) fileserver on CentOs 6.4

The browsing works, I can see the other Computers on the network using *smbtree -N*
The server shows up in the list and is accessible under its dns/host name (FOO), which is different from its netbios name (BAR).

I want to be able to switch the netbios name if the fileserver fails, to something like BAR-BAD. And give the backup server the name *BAR*. This way I wouldn't need to reconfigure the windows clients' mapped drives.

```
[global]
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m 
netbios name = BAR
local master = yes
workgroup = WORKGROUP 
os level = 99
encrypt passwords = yes
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
preferred master = yes
wins support = yes
guest ok = yes
wins proxy = no
dns proxy = no
```

When I do a nmblookup BAR from the server itself I get a failure on the netbios name BAR. It seems that the netbios name setting in smb.conf is being ignored. I have tried many combinations of settings of wins/ master browser / local browser ... to no avail.

Any clues as to what might be going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same problem; CentOS 6.4, the servers hostname ("gateway") is showing on the Windows machine instead of the configured netbios name ("Server")